# Summarise many nodes in Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, graph, neural-network, cytoscape.js

I am building a web app where the user can create a sort of **bipartite graph** like this one:

[image: A 6 x 7 x 12 graph]

Sometimes the user would like to build a **huge** graph, for example a graph in which the topmost layer has 784 nodes, as in the next picture. My application can handle the computation, but the result is ugly and meaningless:

[image: A 6 x 7 x 784 graph]

Do you have any idea for rendering a huge layer without just drawing all the nodes but, instead, *summarising* them with another, prettier representation?

Until now I have thought about putting all the nodes of a "huge" layer in an empty compound node, but of course then it is not possible to draw some edges (so the huge layer would seem as it were disconnected from the graph). Another solution would be to have all layers with more than 100 nodes have exactly 100 nodes, and put them inside a compound node with z-index greater than each node's z-index; but I haven't tried this yet.

If you have some other ideas, or if Cytoscape.js provides a way to summarise large graphs, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could group nodes when the amount in a layer exceeds a certain number (e.g. if you have 100 nodes, you combine them into groups of 25)
I'd do this by iterating over the nodes in the layer, making a new node N for each subgroup (inserting all relevant information needed), and then replacing any mention of the replaced nodes by N in all relevant edges ([finding connected edges](http://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.connectedEdges)).

As I personally generate layouts/nodes in python before sending them to cytoscape for visualization, I'll refrain from posting a potentially ineffecient/incorrect javascript/cytoscape example :)